# Sharepoint permissions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How can I set the permissions for a site where I have access to do everything but NOT view documents?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Kevin and I'm responsible for permissions in SharePoint

In SharePoint, you can grant permissions to a user or group via what we call "permission levels" - essentially sets of permissions. Out of the box we include a few of these like "Read" and "Contribute" and "Design".

It sounds like you want to provide some users with the ability to do more than the Read permission level allows, but disallow the viewing of documents. To accomplish this, you could create a new permission level (site settings > advanced permissions > permission levels). Note: we restrict permission levels from including adding or editing items without the ability to view them

If you, or anyone reading have further questions about this stuff feel free to get a hold of my via email: kevin.davis@microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

Your question is slightly confusing, I'm taking it to mean, you want to stop certain users (or groups of users from accessing documents hosted in your site. (Where you are the site administrator.)).

To do that go into each library, go to settings, then document library settings, permissions for this document library and restrict them as appropriate.